# Having issues with rebuilding raven database

Tags: docker

I am having issues rebuilding Raven db locally

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- BTG Version: 1.1.38

**Steps to replicate**

`btg docker db raven`

**Error**:

```
mattwoodruff@mattwoodruff-Ryzen-5900x ~/repos/bison/eticket (TBT-377) $ btg docker db raven

Resetting raven database...


> @circle9r/raven@2.1.6 db:rebuild
> ts-node -r esm ./database/index.ts

2022-02-23T15:31:49.632Z raven:seed:s3 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.19.0.3:9090
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)
2022-02-23T15:40:33.916Z raven:seed:s3 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.19.0.3:9090
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)
```

**What I have tried**

1. updating docker images
2. restarting services
3. I thought it was running out of mem as it was near max and hung so I created an image with 4 cpus and 12 gb of ram. Still timed out.

```
docker stop raven
docker rm raven
docker run -d --restart always --cpus 4 --memory 12g --name raven -p 5013:5013 --network my-network -e NODE_ENV=dev -e MONGO_DATABASE_URL=mongodb://my-mongodb:27017/raven -e SENTINEL_SERVER_URL=http://sentinel:7000 -e ETICKET_SERVER_URL=http://eticket:5002 -e SWD_SERVER_URL=http://chickfila:5007 -e GOPHER_SERVER_URL=http://gopher:5008 -e LABRADOR_SERVER_URL=http://labrador:4000 -e RAVEN_SERVER_URL=http://raven:5013 -e DA_EMAIL_SERVER_URL=http://da-email:9000 -e S3_ENDPOINT=http://s3mock:9090 -e REDIS_DATABASE_URL=my-redis -e REDIS_DATABASE_PORT=6379 ghcr.io/circle9r/raven
```

4. I am able to hit the [s3mock](http://localhost:9090/bucket) running on port 9090.
5. bypass btg and exec'd into docker image

```
docker exec -it raven bash
$ npm run seed:s3
```

6. ask for help on Stack Overflow

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reseting everything? `btg docker reset` It looks like there's a networking issue, which is done in the initial setup phase

Answer (score 0):

[Docker Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDsSH.png)

[image: Docker Settings]

Attached are my docker settings. I'm on a different platform than you but when I've had timeout issues they were usually related to not having enough resources allocated.

Answer (score 0):

posted publically by mistake :smile:. Moved to private SO